# Is it unpythonic to have classes that are not hashable?

Tags: python, hash

I am arguing with a colleague of mine, whether all Python classes really need to be hashable. We have this class that holds symbolic expressions (something similar to SymPy).

My argument is that since we cannot compare two expressions for equality, hashing should not be allowed. For example the expressions '(x)' and '(1*x)' might compare equal, whereas 'sqrt(x*x*x)' and 'abs(x)*sqrt(x)' might not. Therefore, 'hash()' should throw an error when called with a symbolic expression.

His argument is that you should be able to use all classes as keys in dictionaries and sets. Therefore, they must also be hashable. (I'm putting words in his mouth now, he would have explained it better.).

Who is right? Is it unpythonic or not to have classes that throw errors if you try to hash them?

Comment: The equality operator seems to be essential. I do in fact overload the equality operator. But, for example calling 'x==1' would give not return a bool, but the _expression_ 'x==1'.

Comment: This stuff gets hairy to talk about, since the class in question represent symbolic expressions.

Comment: I would rather the '==' and similar operators be consistent with the hash, and have other operators in the python bindings for combining two subexpressions with a test operation.

Comment: Can the expressions returned by `__eq__()` be meaningfully evaluated in a Boolean context?  Does `if exp1 == exp2` work?  If not, defining `__hash__()` is useless.

Comment: Do you have a specific use case in mind for making the expressions `'(x)'` and `'(1*x)'` compare equal, or just a general idea that it would be useful?

Comment: @RussellBorogove My opinion is not to use the symbolic expressions as hash keys at all. I think that the situation is equivalent to floating point numbers. 5*0.2 might or might not be represented identically equally to 1.0 in floating point precision, even if they are from a mathematical sense. The only time when I think it is ok to use floating points as hash keys is when nothing fatal happens if there are multiple (almost) identical keys.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I see here is that you're working with two different notions of equality. If I understand your comment correctly, you've overridden `__eq__` to return an *expression* combining the two arguments  to `==`. If said expression *evaluates* to True (in some sense), then the two expressions are equal; and if your expression class also implements `__nonzero__` (`__bool__` in Python 3) in such a way that `__nonzero__` returns `True` iff the expression is true, then superficially it seems as though this should work fine.

But in fact, it seems to me that the concept of equality you've defined is a very different concept of equality than the normal concept of equality at work in Python. A fundamental requirement for hashability is that, if two items evaluate as equal, then they should be *completely interchangeable*. And while two of your expression objects may evaluate as "equal," I'm not certain they're interchangeable! After all, `5 + 5` and `8 + 2` evaluate to the same result, but they are not *identical*, are they? And given these two expressions, I suspect many people would expect them to hash to two separate bins in a dictionary!

That behavior would be difficult, however, without giving `__eq__` a more conventional definition. And as the docs say, "[Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable)." So if `__eq__` says that `5 + 5` and `8 + 2` are equal, then they must hash to the same value. That means that to make your expressions hashable as they are now, you'd have to chose a `__hash__` that is able to determine a canonical form *for all expressions that evaluate as equal*. That sounds awfully hard to me.

In short, if these expressions are immutable, and if you redefine `__eq__` to return `True` iff the expressions are *identical* (a stronger requirement than "equal"), then there should be no problem making them hashable. On the other hand, I don't see anything wrong with an unhashable immutable type; and I wouldn't recommend trying to make your expressions hashable without redefining `__eq__`.

So it all comes down to how badly you want to define `__eq__` in an unconventional way. I guess on balance I would go with a conventional definition of `__eq__`, simply to avoid producing unexpected behavior. After all, [special cases aren't special enough to break the rules](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: I picked this as my answer as I think it summarizes all the aspects the best, although many of the other answers had very similar arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A hash function is only useful if you have a well-defined equality test *and* the information taken into account for equality tests is immutable.

By default, all user-defined classes are compared by object identity, and they use the `id()` as hash value.  If you don't override the `==` operator, there is rarely a reason to change this behaviour.  If you *do* override `==`, and the information considered in this operator is immutable (meaning it can't change during the liftime of an instance), you can as well also define a hash function to make the instances hashable.

From your question, I cannot quite tell if these conditions hold.  It isn't "Pythonic" or "Unpythonic" to make a class hashable – the question is rather if the semantics of a class allow hashing or not.

Comment: I am "the colleague".  I'm arguing that for our application, the data is immutable, and a meaningful hash is possible and (at least somewhat) desirable.

Comment: Right now we're overriding the '==' operator, but the hash function is still essentially id().

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of built-in Python types that are not hashable. So it's perfectly Pythonic for a class not to be hashable.

The example you give is a good example of the problems of creating a hashable class, because for an object to be usable as a key in a dictionary, it must implement both `__hash__()` and `__eq__()`. If you can't reliably determine equality, then hashability has no real benefit anyway and implementing it is wasted effort.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly not unpythonic to have unhashable classes, although your reason isn't a usual one I'd give.  The main reason a class might be unhashable is because it's mutable and so its core data is itself unhashable.  This would be the case for classes that wrap a dict or list, for instance.

I don't quite follow your logic on equality comparisons.  You say that you can't compare expressions for equality, but then you say certain expressions might or might not compare equal.  Can you or can you not compare them for equality?  If you can't, it doesn't make sense to say they compare equal or unequal.

Comment: He's saying that a human would consider `x` and `x*1` equal, but that this is problematic for the computer to determine without a lot of additional coding.

Comment: Two expressions might be equivalent, for example always evaluate to the same value, but it is not always to check this. For example, If `x` and `y` are two expressions that are equivalent, `x-y` will give an expression which always evaluate to 0. Equality has the meaning of creating an _expression_ that evaluates to 0 (False) or 1 (True).